# Как задать значение переменной double через TextBox c#

Tags: c#

Как задать значение переменной `double` через `TextBox`?
Вот код: 
Нужно задать значение переменной `l` через `TextBox`?

```
  private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {


            double sum = 0;
            foreach (string s in listBox2.Items)
            {
                sum += double.Parse(s);
            }
            double l = 30000;
            double all = l -= sum;
            label4.Text = ("Остаток:") + all;

            label3.Text = ("Потрачено:") + Convert.ToString(sum);
       }
```

Comment: зачем задавать один и тот же вопрос 2 раза ?

Comment: примерно так же как и в случаи с `listbox`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Примерно так

```
double l;
bool b=double.TryParse(textbox1.Text, out l)
if(b)
 {
   double all = l -= sum;
   label4.Text = ("Остаток:") + all;
   label3.Text = ("Потрачено:") + Convert.ToString(sum);
 }
else
 {
   MessageBox.Show("Введенное значение не корректно");
 }
```

Comment: Сработало. Но почему при запуске программы пишет сообщение "Введенное значение некорректно"?

Comment: значит у вас в программе что то не так написано у меня все нормально работает

Comment: Разобрался,спасибо!